# Airport Evacuation Scene

Tags: plot-explanation, the-foreigner

In the movie [*The Foreigner* (2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1615160/), there is a particular scene that I don't understand.

Near the end of the movie, the police raid the airport looking for the newspaper reporter, and eventually find him/his laptop, grab it, and run through the airport to get it out of the way to safely detonate. Why didn't they evacuate the airport as soon as they discovered the laptop? Allow the passengers/people to exit the airport through certain exits while the police go to another exit, instead of running through the crowd with a bomb that could potentially kill a number of people.

Comment: non-plot answer: drama.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would take much longer to get a calm evacuation from an airport, or even to get an announcement made, than it would to just grab the laptop and make a dash.  Either way, people are at risk.  Grabbing the laptop and running with it is probably the safest way to get it out of the airport.  Can you imagine the confusion of a cop yelling "BOMB!" in a crowded airport??